# SQL Query to provide a database authorization to multiple logins

Tags: mysql, sql-server, qsqlquery, sql-query-store

I need to provide access to a particular database for two logins, but I'm unable to find a proper query, following is the incorrect query ,if someone could help me with the correct one that would be helpful

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<DBName> TO {[USER1] AND [USER2]} ;
```

Comment: you can use count to get no. of login and restrict in your procedure to less than or equal to max login limit

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which database you work. I've been doing similar work for DB SQL Azure. Firstly you need to create a login and user at SQL server level:

`CREATE LOGIN someLogin WITH password='<Password>';`
`CREATE USER someUserName FROM LOGIN someLogin ;`
`GO`

Secondly assign a role to a user at SQL server level:

`EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'someLogin';`
`EXEC sp_addrolemember 'loginmanager', 'someLogin ';`
`GO`

After that, you need to create a database and user for it:

`CREATE DATABASE SomeDB;`
`GO`

Finally you can create a some users at database level  and assign them roles.For this purpose you need to run a query in the context of the database created above:
`CREATE USER [someDBUserName] FOR LOGIN [someLogin];`
`GO`

If necessary you can assign roles for this user:

`EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'someDBUserName';`
`GO`

For SQL AZURE the following database-level roles are available:
`db_owner, db_accessadmin, db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin,`
`db_securityadmin, db_backupoperator, db_denydatareader, db_denydatawriter.`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I'm using sql server 2008 R2 and I have already created two syslogins and now I just want to make these two syslogins as a dbowner of a particular database